# How to handle 403.9 HTTP errors in the web.config file?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Do anyone of you know how to handle XXX.X IIS HTTP errors in a web.config file? I tried doing the following:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="error.aspx">
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="error403.aspx" />
  ...
  <!--NOTE: The following does not work-->
  <error statusCode="403.9" redirect="error403.9.aspx" />
  <!--ENDNOTE-->
  ...
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="error404.aspx" />
  ...
</customErrors>
```

But obviously that didn't worked, because the web.config file expects an integer as the statusCode value.

CONTEXT: WinServer 2003 - ASP.NET 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 403.9 isn't going to be filtered down to .Net anyway.  The whole point of a 403.9 is to say that the web server is already overloaded and it can't handle the request.

So, for this particular example, that won't work.

To further clarify, some of those codes (like 401 and 403) are IIS codes and can only be handled at that level.  So, if you want something specific for 403.9, you'll have to edit the IIS configuration to tell it what to do.